# Show that $x^4-8x^2+(1-m)x+1-c=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$

Tags: functions, tangent-line

I am stuck on the following question:

[image]

My thoughts on how to approach it:

1. Find coefficient of $x$ in $(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$.
2. Equate coefficient to $1-m$
3. Prove that the values are equal. To prove it I thought of setting up $2$ simultaneous equations and finding $a, b, m$ - one where I write $f^\prime(a) = f^\prime(b) = m$ and other where I use $m = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.
4. Use values of $a, b, m$ to find $c$ and prove that $1 - c = \text{coefficient of }x^0$

Problems with this approach:

1. It's a boring algebra bash that is too long and involves $4^{th}$ degree polynomials.
2. It doesn't follow the order of the questions i.e. $a, b, m$ are found before we prove part (c).
3. I am not sure whether it even works.

Any help on a simpler approach will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

$f(x)-g(x)=0$ has repeated roots at $x=a$ and $x=b$, then comparing coefficients (don't miss the $x^3$ term).

See also another post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005999/prove-that-if-px-is-a-quartic-polynomial-then-there-can-only-be-at-most-one-l).

Comment: So, for part (c), something just a verbal explanation like this would suffice?: Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Therefore, $h(a) = h(b) = 0$ and $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$ are factors of h(x). Since there aren't any other factors of $h(x)$, $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$ are repeated roots, yielding $h(x) = (x-a)^2(x-b)^2$.

Comment: But why can't $h(x) = (x-a)^3(x-b)$?

Comment: Tangent at $x=a$ (or $b$) implies double root at $x=a$ (or $b$).  We use up all the powers.

Comment: Okay, thank you!